# How can i store data in table from controller store method? i have two table in one migration file

Tags: laravel-5

> I have created a model with migration file by artisan co
>       mmand
>       php artisan make:model Staff -m
>       Created two table in migration file

```
Schema::create('staffcat', function (Blueprint $table) {
        });
Schema::create('staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        });
```

> Now trying to store data to staffcat table from StaffController by
>   store method. But it's not finding staffcat table  :(
>
> ```
>     I created another model Staffcat. But no luck :(
> Create_staff_table File
> ```

```
<?php

        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
        use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
        use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

        class CreateStaffTable extends Migration
        {
            /**
             * Run the migrations.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function up()
            {
                Schema::create('staffcat', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->bigIncrements('id');
                    $table->string('catname');
                });


                Schema::create('staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->bigIncrements('id');
                    $table->string('user_id');
                    $table->string('name');
                    $table->string('designaton');
                    $table->string('nid')->nullable();
                    $table->date('dob');
                    $table->date('doj');
                    $table->string('blood')->nullable();
                    $table->string('mpoin')->nullable();
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }

            /**
             * Reverse the migrations.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function down()
            {
                Schema::dropIfExists('staffcat');
                Schema::dropIfExists('staff');
            }
        }
```

> Staff Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Staff extends Model
{
    //
}

store method in StaffController

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request,[
            'st_cat_name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $staffinfo = new Staff;
        $staffinfo->catname = $request->input('st_cat_name');
        $staffinfo->save();


        return redirect('/staff')->with('success', 'Staff category Created');
    }
```

> Here is the error message
>       "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gchsc.staffcats' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `staffcats`
>   (`catname`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>
> ```
> I want to store data in staffcat table
> ```

Comment: Did you run `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes i did. I have solved it. We can create multiple table in one migration file but but we need to create Model file for each table.